# ASP.NET MVC: Binding a Complex Type to a Select

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding

I am trying to work out if there is built-in support for binding complex types to form elements.

To use a common hypothetical situation:
I have a Product entity that belongs to a Category - the models look something like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Creating a form to hydrate a new entity that only contains simple value types is nice and simple using the ASP.Net MVC framework, e.g.:

```
public ActionResult Create(Product product);
```

But what about the above scenario where your entities contain other complex types? Are there built-in mechanisms for binding an IEnumerable<*T*> to a drop down list and then automatically hydrating the correct *T* when the form is submitted?

It would be fairly trivial to do it manually - I'm just trying to ascertain what I can have for free out of the box.

Comment: See [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-beta-released.aspx#three) and [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) and [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) for details about model binding.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't yet tried the DefaultModelBinder for complex types, but you could always use [MvcContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib)'s CastleBind (borrowed from the [Castle Project](http://castleproject.org/)) which gives you complex type binding easily, including arrays.

See http://blogger.forgottenskies.com/?p=258

Answer (score 2):

Please check [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2009/05/06/the-s-arp-framework-the-sharpmodelbinder.aspx), as I think that talks about your question, it seems that the S#arp guys have solved it and it's easily "rip"'able if you don't use their stuff.

Anyway I think it's somewhat dangerous to automatically load entities from whatever the user posts... will have to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I think that it will come is overriding the `ToString()` method in the class to output meaningful information to the DropDownList - but not much else.

You may be able to bind the IEnumerable collection to a DropDownList and then retrieving its SelectedItem when the form is submitted - that is the cheapest way I can think of.