# ASP.Net MVC3 Parent Child Model Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model-binding, defaultmodelbinder

I have a partial template that uses a User object as a model. The user has a collection of Accounts. On this partial template I have a loop as follows. The _Account partial template is bound to the Account class

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.Accounts)
            { 
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6">
                        <div>
                            @Html.Partial("_Account", item)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            }
```

In my controller method I initially tried

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult UserDetails(User user, string actionType)
```

But the User.Accounts collection is empty. Then I tried this. Still the Accounts collection is empty.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult UserDetails(User user,  
                             [Bind(Prefix="User.Accounts")]
                             FixupCollection<Account> Accounts, 
                             string actionType)
```

Can I use the default Modelbinder implementation to achieve this or do I need to do anything different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, you can use the default model binder.  You just need to name your fields correctly.  So you need your loop to output something like this:

```
...
<input type="text" name="user.Accounts[0].SomeTextField" />
<input type="text" name="user.Accounts[0].SomeOtherTextField" />
...
<input type="text" name="user.Accounts[1].SomeTextField" />
<input type="text" name="user.Accounts[1].SomeOtherTextField" />
...
```

If you need to add/remove accounts, the hardcoded indexes get a little trickier.  You could re-assign the names using javascript before postback.  But it's all possible.  This question gives more detail on model binding:

[ASP.NET MVC: Binding a Complex Type to a Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554790/asp-net-mvc-binding-a-complex-type-to-a-select)

Comment: :Only issue I find in this is that it exposes your class name in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use Editor Templates instead of a partial view - no need to hard code your indexes as the template will automagically index all your objects correctly, even when you add and remove Accounts. See my answer to this question:

[Pass values from multiple partial views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545634/mvc-passing-values-back-from-multiple-partial-views-in-a-page/11506403#11506403)

Small write up on Editor Templates here:

[codenodes.wordpress.com - MVC3 Editor Templates](http://codenodes.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/mvc-3-editor-templates)