# dropdownlist for a collection within a collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model, something like the following:

```
public class Person
{
   public IEnumerable<SelectList> RelationshipTypeList { get; set; }
   public List<Contacts> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

Each contact has a RelationshipTypeId and also a Name as string.

I want to show, for the person, all the contacts and also a dropdownlist for each contact that has the RelationshipTypeList. So something like:

```
foreach(var currentContact in Model.Contacts)
{
   @Html.LabelFor(m => currentContact.Name)
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => currentContact.RelationshipTypeId, new SelectList(Model.RelationshipTypeList, "Value", "Text", currentContact.RelationshipTypeId))
}
```

Question is, when the user changes the selection from the dropdownlist, how can I make that bind in the model in the Contacts collection for the right contact so essentially the model is updated correctly?

Answer (score 0):

got it working by looking at what gets rendered in the DOM and also this helped:

[ASP.NET MVC 3: Edit a "Collection" of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109893/asp-net-mvc-3-edit-a-collection-of-items)